# React Hook Form - How To Persist Form Data In Redux Upon Changes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hook-form

I want to store the value of fields, upon update, in a redux state property. Is there a way to do this globally for all the form data or do I need to dispatch a separate reducer for each controlled component upon `onChange`/`onValueChange`/`onTextChange`?

By the way, I'm working in React Native, if that matters (thus using some specific patterns such as `control` instead of `register`).

---

Extra info about my form and redux state:
my form has nested children, each containing various custom controlled components. In each of those controlled components, the local form state is updated accordingly (either by passing the new value to `setValue` if it's a custom input).

After getting my local form data updating properly, I persisted the state in redux by dispatching a reducer in `onSubmit`. Because this form creates data associated with one item from a list of items, the reducer stores the form data in a parent object located at `state.listOfItems[index].formData`.